# Access object properties from object function

Tags: javascript

I want to access an object's properties from an object's function.
I have tried:

```
var ui_conf = {
    Conf: {
        "a": "b", 
        "c": "d",
        "f": {}
    },      
    someFunc: function(paramx, paramy) {
       //access conf.a
       console.log(this.Conf) //undefiend
       console.log(window.ui_conf) //undefiend
    },
};
```

Comment: Only way `this` will reference the object is if you *directly invoke* `someFunc` from that object reference. `ui_conf.someFunc(...)`, or if you otherwise explicitly bind it.

Comment: Can you show us how you call your function?

Comment: how are you calling this `someFunc` ?

Comment: `ui_conf.someFunc` - from click event for example.

Comment: Sorry ui_conf.someFunc is a callback.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas: There are many previous questions that address this, but if you pass a method like that, you're *only* passing the method, not the object too. So when it comes time to invoke the function, it no longer has any knowledge of the original object, so it can't set the proper `this` value.

Comment: Toward the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/5764553), there's a section titled "Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks/event handlers" that probably covers the problem.

Comment: Well @AndrewMyers you are right, I forgot to add this part to this question this is why all the downvotes.... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are calling this function with some other reference something like

```
var temp = ui_conf.someFunc;

temp();
```

And that will give you `undefined` against  `this.Conf` as `this` is not a  reference to `ui_conf`.

You may want to try it like

```js
var ui_conf = {
    Conf: {
        "a": "b",
        "c": "d",
        "f": {}
    },

    someFunc: function(paramx, paramy) {
        //access conf.a
        console.log(this.Conf) //undefiend
        console.log(window.ui_conf) //undefiend

    },
};

ui_conf.someFunc();
```

Comment: *"as temp as no property as Conf"* That'll confuse the OP since `this` is not a reference to the `temp` function. Maybe you meant that the `this` value in the `temp` invocation will not have that property, but it sounds like you're suggesting that `this === temp`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain just updated

Comment: *"this will be the reference to temp itself"* That's what I was trying to prevent it sounding like because it's incorrect. The value of `this` is *not* a reference to the `temp` function. It will be the `window` object when the function doesn't know what else to use (or `undefined` in strict mode).

Answer (score 0):

You can call your object's properties from an object function using this way because you have't call your property it only declared in you code:

```js
var ui_conf = { 
                Conf : {
                    "a": "b", 
                    "c": "d",
                    "f": {}
                },
                someFunc: function(paramx, paramy) {
                   console.log(this.Conf) 
                },
            };
ui_conf.someFunc();
```

Comment: You should explain what specifically makes this work so they're not left wondering why it works in some cases and not others.

Comment: Does now work from a `callback`.

Comment: According to @George Bailey you never called your reference that's why your property is undefined.

Comment: If it was never called, he wouldn't be getting `undefined` in the console.